# How can I make myself an "operator" on my own dedicated server?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, server-administration

When playing *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive* on my own dedicated server, I cannot execute certain commands (Ex. "sv_cheats 1", "noclip") via my console. I receive the error:

"Can't change replicated ConVar sv_cheats from console of client, only server operator can change its value."

So the question is, *how can I make my server recognize me as the server operator?*

Comment: Why was this downvoted? ;_;

Comment: This is a valid question with a factual answer and if I've read the about correctly, belongs in arqade. Anyone want to elaborate on how this was off-topic?

Comment: @Cole Nobody said it was off-topic.  It was just downvoted.  Why, I don't know, but I'm just clarifying; there are no close votes on it.

Comment: @fbueckert yeah I can't see that (or at least I don't know how) so I was just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set an rcon password? If so then, `rcon_password somesuperlongandawesomepassword` will elevate your permissions to OP. Once elevated you may then use `rcon sv_cheats 1` to turn on cheats.

BREAKDOWN:

`rcon` - issue remote console command

`sv_cheats` - cheats for server command

`1` - enabled

If not you may still be able to set one from the dedicated server console, OR issue the commands you want there.

[HERE](http://csgoguider.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/how-to-create-a-csgo-dedicated-server/) is a guide I found to set your rcon_password on the server at server launch in the cvar_list.

### OTHER RESOURCES

[Command List](http://wiki.multiplay.co.uk/Csgo/Command_list)

[Sorted Command List](http://wiki.multiplay.co.uk/CS:GO/Command_list)

Comment: I found [this list of console commands on google](https://googledrive.com/host/0B560atMafO-pS0VhQlJERU9oYVk/CS%20GO%20Command%20List%20.txt)